# Proving a complex summation identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, summation

Suppose $b$'s are ordered like $b_{i}\geq b_{i-1}$.

Then in a research article it says

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j>i}^{n}a_{i}a_{j}(b_{j}-b_{i})=\sum_{i=2}^{n}\left[(b_{i}-b_{i-1})\left[\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}a_{j}\right]\left[\sum_{j=i}^{n}a_{j}\right]\right]
$$

I could see that it holds for $n=3$ and $n=4$.

But proving this seems like quite a brain teaser.

Can anyone prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s convenient to let $d_k=b_k-b_{k-1}$ for $k=2,\ldots,n$, so that if $1\le i<j\le n$, then

$$b_j-b_i=\sum_{k=i+1}^jd_k\;.$$

Then

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^na_ia_j(b_j-b_i)&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^na_ia_j\sum_{k=i+1}^jd_k\\\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^n\sum_{k=i+1}^ja_ia_jd_k\\\\
&=\sum_{1\le i<k\le j\le n}a_ia_jd_k\\\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\sum_{j=k}^na_ia_jd_k\\\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^nd_k\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\sum_{j=k}^na_ia_j\\\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^nd_k\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\left(a_i\sum_{j=k}^na_j\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^nd_k\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=k}^na_j\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^n(b_k-b_{k-1})\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=k}^na_j\right)\;,
\end{align*}$$

as desired. The key is seeing that we’re really summing over all combinations of indices $i,j,k$ such that $1\le i<k\le j\le n$ and breaking this set of combinations up in two different ways.

Comment: Thank you very much! What type of textbook, or what type of subject, should I learn to have the kind of skill and idea to solve problems like this?